# error when using if condition in Ajax code

Tags: ajax

I want to change **var Rs** on value **Price** field
some data fields have price and some don't there for I need to change that logically

I want to change **var Rs** on value **Price** field
some data fields have price and some don't there for I need to change that logically

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
AllAddData();
function AllAddData(query = '') {
$("#Published").empty();
$.ajax({
url: 'AllAdds',
type: 'GET',
datatype:'html',
data:{SearchKey:query},
})
.done(function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, val) {

  if(!empty(val.Price)){
  var Rs ="{{ __('Rs.') }}"+val.Price;} 
  else{var Rs ="";}

});
})

.fail(function() 
{
alert("fail")
console.log("error");
})
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){    
                var query = $("#search").val();
                //alert(query);   
                AllAddData(query);
            });

        });
</script>
```

[image: output]

[image: ajax code]

Comment: what does `data` has in it ? Also , elaborate more on your problem .

Comment: some price fields are empty, when its empty want to update var Rs empty else want to update var Rs ="{{ __('Rs.') }}"+val.Price;}

Comment: where you need to do this ? where should this gets display ? are you going to change inside json ?

Comment: $('#Published').append('<div

Comment: im going to make variable and that data print using .append

Comment: i see so did you tried appending it that way ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: no, its running

Comment: can you show output of `data` ?

Comment: attached as images

Comment: Try  : `var Rs = !(value) ? "{{ __('Rs.') }}" + value : ""`

Comment: var Rs = !(val.Price) ? "" :"{{ __('Rs.') }}" + val.Price

Comment: thanks dear, its working ....

Answer (score 0):

var Rs = !(val.Price) ? "" :"{{ __('Rs.') }}" + val.Price